# Use okhttp to do post request with integer values

Tags: android, okhttp

I am trying to send POST request to server with body.
Some body values are expected fo be integers and double not strings.

I am using the multipart builder with okhttp but it only accepts string values in a name-value pair

How can I send integer values as integers (no quotes)

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to send integers? Server side will look only the data. So, you can use `String.valueOf(_int_)` just in-case incoming values are integers.

Comment: The server expects integer  not string integer. It fails with string integer and pass with integer

Comment: You should post part of server code here. How it fails & the code it runs.

Comment: Not my server, it is Fitbit Web api https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/food-logging

Comment: *Not quite sure if it will work, but at least try this solution* -> 
`String.valueOf(YOUR_INTEGER_NUM).replace("\"","")`

I think the integer is getting wrapped by some `"` . So, it looks internally something like "\"12345\"".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for `multipart/form-data` values is a raw unquoted string. So there is no difference between an integer and a string, as there is in a format like JSON. Each field in a request with `Content-Type` `multipart/form-data` can have its own `Content-Type` defined as well. A field could be `application/json` with a JSON text value, `text/html` with HTML text value, or even `application/octet` containing raw binary data.

A raw request is in a format like this:

```
POST /example.com HTTP/1.1
<additional headers>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=vzgD3VXVRH
Content-Length: 1250

--vzgD3VXVRH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="string"

text value
--vzgD3VXVRH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="number"

12345
--vzgD3VXVRH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"; filename="example.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{"string":"text value","number":12345}
--vzgD3VXVRH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"; filename="example.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
--vzgD3VXVRH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="html"; filename="example.html"
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Page Title</title></head>
<body><h1>Simple HTML doc</h1></body>
</html>
--vzgD3VXVRH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binary"; filename="example.bin"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<raw binary data>
--vzgD3VXVRH--
```

More info on the multipart/form-data spec [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578).

**Update:**

With the clarification that you are posting a request to [this API](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/food-logging/#logging-and-deleting-collection-data), you should be able to post a request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form parameters instead of `multipart/form-data`. `multipart/form-data` is more appropriate for requests that post binary data or upload files.

You can do this in OkHttp as follows:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
String userId = "12345";

RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("mealTypeId", "7")
        .add("unitId", "321")
        .add("amount", "4.25")
        .add("date", "2019-03-18")
        .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/" + userId + "/foods/log.json")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: In this case how can modify the content type of each field. If I use Postman app and pass integer it works but if I pass string then it fails. So in okhttp I am trying somehow to pass integer so quotes dont appear

Comment: Please share your code to give a better idea of what you're doing and trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to call https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/food-logging/#logging-and-deleting-collection-data and some values it accepts are integer

Comment: Please share the code you're using to construct the multipart/form-data HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you ,I found a different way by appending parameters to request but I will accept this answer as  the correct as it makes sense